# Making a static datasource

Tags: java, datasource, initial-context

I have done enough research on this topic, but yet to find a concrete answer for this. Following is the code snippet,

```
private static Map<String,DataSource> dataSourceMap;

    static {
      Map<String,DataSource> jndiContextDataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
      try {
        jndiContextDataSourceMap.put(JNDI_DEFAULT_DATASOURCE, (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_DEFAULT_DATASOURCE));
      } catch (NamingException namingException) {
        logger.error("Unable to obtain default DataSource through JNDI Lookup.", namingException);
      }
      try {
        jndiContextDataSourceMap.put(JNDI_READ_REPLICA, (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_READ_REPLICA));
      } catch (NamingException namingException) {
        logger.error("Unable to obtain read only DataSource through JNDI Lookup.", namingException);
      }
      dataSourceMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(jndiContextDataSourceMap);
    }
```

Is it fine to use same `DataSource` object? I checked the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), but that contains really no specifics on the thread-safety.

I am using this to avoid `lookup` and to avoid creating a new `InitialContext` for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be alright. Since `DataSource` is responsible for providing a `Connection`, it would be a very poor idea not to make it thread-safe. Most programs use multiple connections concurrently after all. It might not be documented as thread-safe and [it's not specified that it should be thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), but any *sane* implementation is thread-safe.

Comment: "should be alright" is different from, "it is alright" . Right? And, would be grateful if you could explain why as well codewise.

Comment: Well like I said, nothing stops you from writing a non-threadsafe `DataSource`, but it would be completely unusable for anything but a single threaded application.